# CSS border-radius applied ONLY to the last fieldset in form-element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a web application for calculating dates.

I like to have a border with rounded edges around my fieldset elements.
The border radius works fine. But the border-radius is applied **only** to the last fieldset element.

What's the reason why it isn't applied to **all** fieldset elements?

```js
var oo = {};
 
 Object.defineProperty(oo, 'MILLI_SECONDS_DAY',  {
     value: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
   });
 
    oo.elements = [];
 
 oo.resultDate = document.getElementById('result-date');
 oo.setDays = document.getElementById('set-days'); 
    oo.elements[0] = document.getElementById('set-day');
 oo.elements[1] = document.getElementById('set-weeks');
 oo.radioControls = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-control');
 oo.dateSelects = document.querySelectorAll('.date-select');
 
 oo.toggleDisable = function() {
   // The main parent node of the choosen fieldset.
   var fieldset = this.parentNode.parentNode;
   // The all input elements within it.
   var selects = fieldset.querySelectorAll('.date-select');
   // Disable all input elements.
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(oo.dateSelects, function(dateSelect) {
     if (!dateSelect.disabled) {
    dateSelect.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    dateSelect.parentNode.classList.remove('active-select');
     }
   });
   // Re-Enable all inputs in the current chosen fieldset.
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(selects, function(select) {
     if (select.disabled && select !== this) {
    select.removeAttribute('disabled');
    select.parentNode.classList.add('active-select');
     }
   });
 }
 
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(oo.radioControls, function(radioControl) {
   radioControl.addEventListener('change', oo.toggleDisable);
 });
 
 for (var i = 0; i < oo.elements.length; i++) {
   oo.elements[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
  oo.resultDate.value =
    oo.getDayMonthYearDate( 
      oo.getDateBeforeIn( oo.elements[0].value,
                    oo.elements[1].value ) );
   });   
 }
 
 oo.setDays.addEventListener('change', function() {
  oo.resultDate.value =
    oo.getDayMonthYearDate( 
      oo.getDateBeforeInDays(oo.setDays.value) );
   }); 
 
 oo.setOptions = function(selectElement, countOptionsStart, countOptionsEnd) {
   for (var i = countOptionsStart; i <= countOptionsEnd; i++) {
     var option = document.createElement('option');
     var optionInner = document.createTextNode(i);
   
     option.setAttribute('value', i);
   
     if (i === 0) option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
   
     option.appendChild(optionInner);
     selectElement.appendChild(option);   
   }
 }
 
 oo.setOptions(oo.elements[1], -52, 52);
 oo.setOptions(oo.setDays, -365, 365);
  
    // Returns a Date Object which contains
 // the date before/in n-days and 
 // before/in n-weeks.
 
 // -- Parameter ----------------------------
 // 1. String - The desired weekday as an 
    //   abbreviation.
 //   Assign for ...
 //     Monday    : 'mo'
 //     Tuesday   : 'tu'
 //     Wednesday : 'we'
 //     Thursday  : 'th'
 //     Friday    : 'fr'
 //     Saturday  : 'sa'
 //     Sunday    : 'su'
 
 // 2. Number - Positive number => n-weeks in
 //   the future.
 //   Negative number => n-weeks before.
 
 // -- Return -------------------------------
 // (Date) Object 
 
    oo.getDateBeforeIn = function(day, weeks) {
   var currentDate = new Date();
   var currentStamp = Date.now();   
   var weekdays = {
     'mo': 1,
  'tu': 2,
  'we': 3,
  'th': 4,
  'fr': 5,
  'sa': 6,
  'su': 0
   }   
 
   currentStamp += weeks * 7 * oo.MILLI_SECONDS_DAY;
      currentStamp +=
     (weekdays[day] - currentDate.getDay()) *
   oo.MILLI_SECONDS_DAY;   
   
   return new Date(currentStamp);
 }
 
 oo.getDateBeforeInDays = function(days) {
   var currentDate = new Date();
   var currentStamp = Date.now();
   
   currentStamp += days * oo.MILLI_SECONDS_DAY;
   
   return new Date(currentStamp);
 }
 
 // Returns the Day, Month, Year of an 
 // JavaScript Date Object as as String
 // in the Date format DMY.
 
 // -- Parameter ----------------------------
 // 1. Date-Object
 // 2. String - Is used for separating 
 // Day-Year and Month-Year.
 
 // -- Return -------------------------------
 // String
 
 oo.getDayMonthYearDate = function(dateObject, separator) {
   separator = separator || '.';
   
   return oo.getZeroPaddedNumber(dateObject.getDate(), 2) +
          separator +
          oo.getZeroPaddedNumber((dateObject.getMonth() + 1), 2) +
    separator + dateObject.getFullYear();
 }
 
 oo.getZeroPaddedNumber = function(someNumber, desiredLength) {
   someNumber = '00' + someNumber;
   
   return someNumber.slice(desiredLength * -1);
 }
```

```css
body {
   font-family: tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif;
   background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0);
 }
  
    #wrap {
   max-width: 950px;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 input, select, label {
   margin: 10px;
 }
 
 #form-set-date {
   padding: 10px 20px;
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(250, 250, 250, 1.0), rgba(220, 220, 220, 1.0));
   border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.6);
   border-radius: 12px;
 }

 .control-element {
   margin: 10px 0;
   width: 280px;
   background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1.0);
   border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
   border-radius: 9px;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .active-select:hover {
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 180, 180, 1.0);
   box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 220, 220, 1.0);
 }
 
 .control-element label {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
 }
 
 .read-only[disabled=disabled] {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
   text-align: center;
 }
 
 #set-day {
   width: 110px;
 }
 
 input[type=radio] {
   width: 30px;
 }
 
 input[type=text], select {
   width: 100px;
 }

 fieldset:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
   margin-top: 20px;
 }
 
 fieldset {
   border-radius: 12px;
   border: 3px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <form method="" action="" id="form-set-date">
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Specify date by weekday and week(s)</legend>
       <div class="control-element active-select">
         <input type="radio" id="by-days-weeks" value="daysWeeks" 
            class="radio-control" checked="checked"
       name="radio-control" />
      <label for="by-days-weeks" 
          class="radio-label" >Set active</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="control-element active-select">
     <label>Weekday: </label>
     <select id="set-day" class="date-select">
    <option value="mo">Monday</option>
    <option value="tu">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="we">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="th">Thursday</option>
    <option value="fr">Friday</option>
    <option value="sa">Saturday</option>
    <option value="su">Sunday</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="control-element active-select">
   <label>Week(s): </label>
   <select id="set-weeks" class="date-select"></select>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Specify date by days</legend>
       <div class="control-element active-select">
         <input type="radio" id="by-days" value="days" 
          class="radio-control"
       name="radio-control" />
  
      <label for="by-days" 
          class="radio-label" >Set active</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="control-element">
   <label>Days: </label>
   <select id="set-days" class="date-select"
           disabled="disabled" ></select>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>  
  <div class="control-element">
    <label>Result: </label>
    <input type="text" class="read-only" id="result-date" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Chrome and the border radius is there for all 3 fieldsets

Comment: the border radius works fine [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upL1fyLq/)... you should inspect your page and see if your css is overridden

Comment: Added a screenshot. Perhaps an Internet Explorer issue? We aren't allowed to use anything else here. At least we got Internet Explorer 11 since a few months.

Comment: Firefox has all the border radius too!

Comment: @bo256... you have required as screenshot image ? am i right ?

Comment: @Mansukh Khandbar : Sorry. Don't understand your question ...

Comment: @bo256 : You want to do same as your screenshot ?

Comment: No. I just added the screenshot for to show how it looks on my browser.